# How to enable file previews in Ranger running on Proxmox by default?

Tags: ranger

I installed Ranger on a Proxmox LXC (Debian 12.2), MacOS and Raspbian 11. All installed versions are 1.9.3. When running it on MacOS or on Raspbian, the file previews work fine. When I run it on Debian, I have to press "zp" every time to see file previews.

I tried copying the config with `ranger --copy-config=all`, modifying `~/.config/ranger/rc.conf` and ensuring that these lines are present:

```
set preview_files true
set preview_directories true
set collapse_preview false
```

It shows the preview "panel" and the directory contents are showing up fine. However, when navigating over files (I tried selecting .txt, .md, .yml, .conf), the preview panel is blank.

When I press "zp" then the files show up just fine. I made no changes to any config files.

Running `ranger --debug` does not produce any errors.

`ranger --version` output on Debian:

```
ranger version: ranger 1.9.3
Python version: 3.11.2 (main, Mar 13 2023, 12:18:29) [GCC 12.2.0]
Locale: en_US.UTF-8
```

`ranger --version` output on RPi:

```
ranger version: ranger 1.9.3
Python version: 3.9.2 (default, Mar 12 2021, 04:06:34) [GCC 10.2.1 20210110]
Locale: en_US.UTF-8
```

Am I missing a required application or some other config option?

The same behavior (preview not working by default) is observed in a Debian docker container and on the host OS of Proxmox (running on bare metal).